# Hover on 1 child - hide other parents which are inside other divs - Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I hover 1 child, I try to hide other parents div ( child including ) except the child hovered and its parent.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this very similar, but reversed, and can't find a way to make it work.

[Hover on 1 child - hide other children which are inside other divs, css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403135/hover-on-1-child-hide-other-children-which-are-inside-other-divs-css-only)

```
$('.dep').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().children().not(this).find('.dim').css({'opacity' : '1'})
}, function() {
  $('.dim').css({'opacity' : '0'})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is once you've found the **[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**, simply hide the **[`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** by setting their `opacity` to `0`. You'll also want to **show** the one you're hovering over by setting the **[`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)** to `1`, as can be seen in the following:

```js
$('.child').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().css({
    'opacity': '0'
  })
}, function() {
  $('.parent').css({
    'opacity': '1'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Child 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Child 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Child 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```